# How do I update the view when the model does not change?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example if I have a picture that changes on the server, nothing on the front end model changes.  Nothing changes on the server side SQL.  The only thing that changes is the file.

In this case it is just a user pic.

There are of course a number of ways to do this, but what is the standard way of doing this?

Should I just fire a model change event manually to get the view to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually send a `trigger`

this would happen if you would `set` something, so you can skip this and `trigger` yourself.

```
model.trigger('user pic changed', model, value, var3)
```

and you can listen to it:

```
this.listenTo(this, 'user pic changed', this.doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useless property on your model :

```
myModel.set( 'useless', myModel.get( 'useless' ) + 1 );
```

and your view will be updated

Comment: It may be, but I never found this way :)